# Adding all file feature data (shapefiles) from folder into an MXD with ArcPy

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I want to ask about scripting using ArcPy for handling feature data inside an ArcGIS map document (MXD).

I have a folder that has some feature data in shapefile (shp) form.

- D:\tes\2240.shp
- D:\tes\2250.shp
- D:\tes\22460.shp
- etc.

I want to create an ArcPy script that can add the data above to an MXD. I can add files individually using this script:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\tes\Operation.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Actual", df)[0]
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\data\2440.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "TOP")
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\data\2450.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "TOP")
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\data\2460.shp")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "TOP")
mxd.saveACopy(r"D:\tes\Operation_2.mxd")
del mxd, addLayer
```

I want to change the path source data of the script above, at this part

```
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\data\2440.shp")
```

so the script can add all shp data in the folder using the extension, not each file name hardcoded. Something kind of like this:

```
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\data\*.shp")
```

What's the proper way to do that?

Comment: You need to include code showing what you have tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Create a list of all the shapefiles in the directory](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfiles.htm), then loop through it.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\tes\Operation.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

# set workspace to directory of interest
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\data"
# create list of all files ending in .shp
list_shapefiles = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")

targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Actual", df)[0]
# loop through list, adding each shapefile to group layer
for shapefile in list_shapefiles:
    addLayer = shapefile
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, addLayer, "TOP")

mxd.saveACopy(r"D:\tes\Operation_2.mxd")
```

Comment: Thank you @erica, your code will help me to solve my problem، but I wonder if there is an Arcgis tool enable to import shapefiles without coding, like "load them all" plugin for qgis. Thank's

Comment: @nermiiine I thought the "add data" button lets you select multiple shapefiles to add at once -- is that no longer the case?

Comment: But I have a folder which contain multiple subfolders which also contain multiple shapefiles, so I want to connect to folder and open all this shapefiles. I hope I was clear.

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than commenting here :)  I don't know a solution for you but the rest of the community might, and a new question will get you more attention.